# $_POST value not getting set on $.ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I'm new to PHP and javascript and I've run into a problem where I need to edit values in an xml document that is read in. I have an HTML Select that has been dynamically created by PHP code.

```
function outputTableRow() {
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
        echo "<select onchange=\"ValueChange(this);\">";
            echo "<option value=\"not value\" selected >No selection</option>";
            echo "<option value=\"A\" >A</option>";
            echo "<option value=\"B\" >B</option>";
            echo "<option value=\"C\" >C</option>";
            echo "<option value=\"D\" >D</option>";
        echo "</select>";
    echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```

The onchange event for the select then calls a javascript function that (as far as my understanding goes) performs an ajax request to the _POST of that same php document.

```
function ValueChange(obj)
{
    var value = obj.value;

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "functions.php",
    data: "callFunction=UpdateValue"
    });
}
```

From there I try to check the value set by the ajax request in _POST to call the appropriate function.

```
if(isset($_POST['callFunction'])){
    if($_POST['callFunction'] == 'UpdateValue'){
       UpdateValue();
    }
}
```

And finally in the function I'm trying to get to, I'm trying to write a console log when that code is reached but it never get's there. In fact, the _POST is always empty.

```
function UpdateValue()
{
   echo '<script>console.log("VALUE CHANGE")</script>';
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `echo "<onchange=\"ValueChange(this);\">";` are you missing something?

Comment: Sorry, it is a proper select tag, I was just removing css extras and got a little carried away

Comment: Instead of looking for things in your console, look at the output HTML. Does it contain the `<script>` element?

Comment: you are assuming that $.ajax will render a script tag, your assumptions are wrong

Comment: Yes the script gets called, I had alerts set up so I know it got there. It's just the jQuery that I'm not sure about

Comment: There's no success callback in the ajax function.

Comment: ya, I was trying to say that, please use success, error, done function as proper jQuery coding principles

Comment: missing success:function(ss){ alert(ss); }

Comment: Can I ask for a brief description of what that does, or a link to some useful documentation?

Comment: Just writing up an answer for you now

Comment: Looks like that was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) is how you should be outputting blocks of HTML:

```
<?php
function outputTableRow() {
    echo <<< HTML
<tr>
    <td>
        <select onchange="ValueChange(this);">
            <option value="not value" selected >No selection</option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
            <option value="D">D</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
HTML;
}
```

Then you'll want to add a [success callback](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to your Ajax function:

```
function ValueChange(obj)
{
    var value = obj.value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "functions.php",
        data: "callFunction=UpdateValue",
        success: function(data) {$(body).append(data);}
    });
}
```

Really you should also be using jQuery to bind events instead of using `onchange` attribute as well. Assuming you gave the select `id="changer"` it would look something like this:

```
$("select#changer").on("change", function() {ValueChange(this);});
```

Answer (score -1):

It's posible that the URL in Ajax call is bad, it must contain the server o something like that, you can try with ´URL: "http://localhost/functions.php"´